# javascript output does not show if i check for length of value (textfield)

Tags: javascript, html

I have this issue where if I add a certain if statement, the entire function does not show the error and somehow refreshes the webpage, only showing the if statement output for a second before disappearing. Ill provide the javascript code, but ill post html as well if it needs checking.

this javascript code works normally:

```
document.getElementById("register").onclick = function () {

var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
var lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
var contact = document.getElementById("contact").value;
var birthday = document.getElementById("birthdate").value;
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var passwd = document.getElementById("passwd").value;
var c_passwd = document.getElementById("c_passwd").value;

  if (!fname) {
    document.getElementById("fname_label").innerHTML = "<span style='color: red;'>Please enter your first name</span>";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("fname_label").innerHTML = "First Name";
  }

  if (!lname) {
    document.getElementById("lname_label").innerHTML = "<span style='color: red;'>Please enter your last name</span>";
  } else {

  }

  if (!contact) {
    document.getElementById("number_label").innerHTML = "<span style='color: red;'>Please enter your contact number (must contain 11 digits)</span>";
  }


  if (!birthday) {
    document.getElementById("birthdate_label").innerHTML = "<span style='color: red;'>Please select your birthday</span>";
  } else {

  }

  if (!email || email != '@') {
    document.getElementById("email_label").innerHTML = "<span style='color: red;'>Please enter your complete email address</span>";
  } else {

  }

  if (!passwd || !c_passwd) {
    document.getElementById("password_label").innerHTML = "<span style='color: red;'>Please enter your password</span>";
    document.getElementById("c_password_label").innerHTML = "<span style='color: red;'>Please confirm your password</span>";
  } else {

  }

  if (passwd != c_passwd) {
     document.getElementById("password_label").innerHTML = "<span style='color: red;'>Passwords do not match</span>";
     document.getElementById("c_password_label").innerHTML = "<span style='color: red;'>Passwords do not match</span>";
   } else {

   }
return false;
}
```

OUTPUT:
[image: 1]

now when I try to add:

```
  if (contact.val().length !== 11) {
    document.getElementById("number_label").innerHTML = "<span style='color: red;'>Invalid contact number (must contain 11 digits)</span>";
  }
```

which will be used to see if the contact textfield has exactly 11 digits, the output only shows the errors up to the contact (so no bday, email, pwd) for just a second and disappears. (i cant screenshot the error since it reloads as soon as it appears)

HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="register.php" method="post" onsubmit="return checkform()">
      <div class="container rg_box">
        <br>

        <label id="fname_label"><b>First Name</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname" autocomplete="off"
        value="<?php
          if(isset($_POST["fname"])) {
            echo($_POST["fname"]);
          } ?>">

        <label id="lname_label"><b>Last Name</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control" id="lname" name="lname" autocomplete="off"
        value="<?php
          if(isset($_POST["lname"])) {
            echo($_POST["lname"]);
          } ?>">

        <label id="number_label"><b>Contact Number</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Contact Number" class="form-control" id="contact" name="contact" autocomplete="off"
        value="<?php
          if(isset($_POST["contact"])) {
            echo($_POST["contact"]);
          } ?>">

        <label id="birthdate_label"><b>Birthday</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Birthdate" class="form-control" id="birthdate" name="birthdate" autocomplete="off"
        value="<?php
          if(isset($_POST["birthdate"])) {
            echo($_POST["birthdate"]);
          } ?>">

        <label><b>Country</b></label>
        <select class="form-control" name="country" autocomplete="off">
          <option value="United States">United States</option>
          <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
          <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
          <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
          <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
          <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
          <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
          <option value="Angola">Angola</option>
          <option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
          <option value="Antarctica">Antarctica</option>
          <option value="Antigua and Barbuda">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
          <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
          <option value="Armenia">Armenia</option>
          <option value="Aruba">Aruba</option>
          <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
          <option value="Austria">Austria</option>
          <option value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option>
          <option value="Bahamas">Bahamas</option>
          <option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option>
          <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
          <option value="Barbados">Barbados</option>
          <option value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
          <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
          <option value="Belize">Belize</option>
          <option value="Benin">Benin</option>
          <option value="Bermuda">Bermuda</option>
          <option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option>
          <option value="Bolivia">Bolivia</option>
          <option value="Bosnia and Herzegovina">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
          <option value="Botswana">Botswana</option>
          <option value="Bouvet Island">Bouvet Island</option>
          <option value="Brazil">Brazil</option>
          <option value="British Indian Ocean Territory">British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
          <option value="Brunei Darussalam">Brunei Darussalam</option>
          <option value="Bulgaria">Bulgaria</option>
          <option value="Burkina Faso">Burkina Faso</option>
          <option value="Burundi">Burundi</option>
          <option value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option>
          <option value="Cameroon">Cameroon</option>
          <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
          <option value="Cape Verde">Cape Verde</option>
          <option value="Cayman Islands">Cayman Islands</option>
          <option value="Central African Republic">Central African Republic</option>
          <option value="Chad">Chad</option>
          <option value="Chile">Chile</option>
          <option value="China">China</option>
          <option value="Christmas Island">Christmas Island</option>
          <option value="Cocos (Keeling) Islands">Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option>
          <option value="Colombia">Colombia</option>
          <option value="Comoros">Comoros</option>
          <option value="Congo">Congo</option>
          <option value="Congo, The Democratic Republic of The">Congo, The Democratic Republic of The</option>
          <option value="Cook Islands">Cook Islands</option>
          <option value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option>
          <option value="Cote D'ivoire">Cote D'ivoire</option>
          <option value="Croatia">Croatia</option>
          <option value="Cuba">Cuba</option>
          <option value="Cyprus">Cyprus</option>
          <option value="Czech Republic">Czech Republic</option>
          <option value="Denmark">Denmark</option>
          <option value="Djibouti">Djibouti</option>
          <option value="Dominica">Dominica</option>
          <option value="Dominican Republic">Dominican Republic</option>
          <option value="Ecuador">Ecuador</option>
          <option value="Egypt">Egypt</option>
          <option value="El Salvador">El Salvador</option>
          <option value="Equatorial Guinea">Equatorial Guinea</option>
          <option value="Eritrea">Eritrea</option>
          <option value="Estonia">Estonia</option>
          <option value="Ethiopia">Ethiopia</option>
          <option value="Falkland Islands (Malvinas)">Falkland Islands (Malvinas)</option>
          <option value="Faroe Islands">Faroe Islands</option>
          <option value="Fiji">Fiji</option>
          <option value="Finland">Finland</option>
          <option value="France">France</option>
          <option value="French Guiana">French Guiana</option>
          <option value="French Polynesia">French Polynesia</option>
          <option value="French Southern Territories">French Southern Territories</option>
          <option value="Gabon">Gabon</option>
          <option value="Gambia">Gambia</option>
          <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
          <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
          <option value="Ghana">Ghana</option>
          <option value="Gibraltar">Gibraltar</option>
          <option value="Greece">Greece</option>
          <option value="Greenland">Greenland</option>
          <option value="Grenada">Grenada</option>
          <option value="Guadeloupe">Guadeloupe</option>
          <option value="Guam">Guam</option>
          <option value="Guatemala">Guatemala</option>
          <option value="Guinea">Guinea</option>
          <option value="Guinea-bissau">Guinea-bissau</option>
          <option value="Guyana">Guyana</option>
          <option value="Haiti">Haiti</option>
          <option value="Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands">Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands</option>
          <option value="Holy See (Vatican City State)">Holy See (Vatican City State)</option>
          <option value="Honduras">Honduras</option>
          <option value="Hong Kong">Hong Kong</option>
          <option value="Hungary">Hungary</option>
          <option value="Iceland">Iceland</option>
          <option value="India">India</option>
          <option value="Indonesia">Indonesia</option>
          <option value="Iran, Islamic Republic of">Iran, Islamic Republic of</option>
          <option value="Iraq">Iraq</option>
          <option value="Ireland">Ireland</option>
          <option value="Israel">Israel</option>
          <option value="Italy">Italy</option>
          <option value="Jamaica">Jamaica</option>
          <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
          <option value="Jordan">Jordan</option>
          <option value="Kazakhstan">Kazakhstan</option>
          <option value="Kenya">Kenya</option>
          <option value="Kiribati">Kiribati</option>
          <option value="Korea, Democratic People's Republic of">Korea, Democratic People's Republic of</option>
          <option value="Korea, Republic of">Korea, Republic of</option>
          <option value="Kuwait">Kuwait</option>
          <option value="Kyrgyzstan">Kyrgyzstan</option>
          <option value="Lao People's Democratic Republic">Lao People's Democratic Republic</option>
          <option value="Latvia">Latvia</option>
          <option value="Lebanon">Lebanon</option>
          <option value="Lesotho">Lesotho</option>
          <option value="Liberia">Liberia</option>
          <option value="Libyan Arab Jamahiriya">Libyan Arab Jamahiriya</option>
          <option value="Liechtenstein">Liechtenstein</option>
          <option value="Lithuania">Lithuania</option>
          <option value="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</option>
          <option value="Macao">Macao</option>
          <option value="Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of">Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of</option>
          <option value="Madagascar">Madagascar</option>
          <option value="Malawi">Malawi</option>
          <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
          <option value="Maldives">Maldives</option>
          <option value="Mali">Mali</option>
          <option value="Malta">Malta</option>
          <option value="Marshall Islands">Marshall Islands</option>
          <option value="Martinique">Martinique</option>
          <option value="Mauritania">Mauritania</option>
          <option value="Mauritius">Mauritius</option>
          <option value="Mayotte">Mayotte</option>
          <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
          <option value="Micronesia, Federated States of">Micronesia, Federated States of</option>
          <option value="Moldova, Republic of">Moldova, Republic of</option>
          <option value="Monaco">Monaco</option>
          <option value="Mongolia">Mongolia</option>
          <option value="Montserrat">Montserrat</option>
          <option value="Morocco">Morocco</option>
          <option value="Mozambique">Mozambique</option>
          <option value="Myanmar">Myanmar</option>
          <option value="Namibia">Namibia</option>
          <option value="Nauru">Nauru</option>
          <option value="Nepal">Nepal</option>
          <option value="Netherlands">Netherlands</option>
          <option value="Netherlands Antilles">Netherlands Antilles</option>
          <option value="New Caledonia">New Caledonia</option>
          <option value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option>
          <option value="Nicaragua">Nicaragua</option>
          <option value="Niger">Niger</option>
          <option value="Nigeria">Nigeria</option>
          <option value="Niue">Niue</option>
          <option value="Norfolk Island">Norfolk Island</option>
          <option value="Northern Mariana Islands">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
          <option value="Norway">Norway</option>
          <option value="Oman">Oman</option>
          <option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
          <option value="Palau">Palau</option>
          <option value="Palestinian Territory, Occupied">Palestinian Territory, Occupied</option>
          <option value="Panama">Panama</option>
          <option value="Papua New Guinea">Papua New Guinea</option>
          <option value="Paraguay">Paraguay</option>
          <option value="Peru">Peru</option>
          <option value="Philippines" selected="selected">Philippines</option>
          <option value="Pitcairn">Pitcairn</option>
          <option value="Poland">Poland</option>
          <option value="Portugal">Portugal</option>
          <option value="Puerto Rico">Puerto Rico</option>
          <option value="Qatar">Qatar</option>
          <option value="Reunion">Reunion</option>
          <option value="Romania">Romania</option>
          <option value="Russian Federation">Russian Federation</option>
          <option value="Rwanda">Rwanda</option>
          <option value="Saint Helena">Saint Helena</option>
          <option value="Saint Kitts and Nevis">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
          <option value="Saint Lucia">Saint Lucia</option>
          <option value="Saint Pierre and Miquelon">Saint Pierre and Miquelon</option>
          <option value="Saint Vincent and The Grenadines">Saint Vincent and The Grenadines</option>
          <option value="Samoa">Samoa</option>
          <option value="San Marino">San Marino</option>
          <option value="Sao Tome and Principe">Sao Tome and Principe</option>
          <option value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option>
          <option value="Senegal">Senegal</option>
          <option value="Serbia and Montenegro">Serbia and Montenegro</option>
          <option value="Seychelles">Seychelles</option>
          <option value="Sierra Leone">Sierra Leone</option>
          <option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
          <option value="Slovakia">Slovakia</option>
          <option value="Slovenia">Slovenia</option>
          <option value="Solomon Islands">Solomon Islands</option>
          <option value="Somalia">Somalia</option>
          <option value="South Africa">South Africa</option>
          <option value="South Georgia and The South Sandwich Islands">South Georgia and The South Sandwich Islands</option>
          <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
          <option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option>
          <option value="Sudan">Sudan</option>
          <option value="Suriname">Suriname</option>
          <option value="Svalbard and Jan Mayen">Svalbard and Jan Mayen</option>
          <option value="Swaziland">Swaziland</option>
          <option value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
          <option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option>
          <option value="Syrian Arab Republic">Syrian Arab Republic</option>
          <option value="Taiwan, Province of China">Taiwan, Province of China</option>
          <option value="Tajikistan">Tajikistan</option>
          <option value="Tanzania, United Republic of">Tanzania, United Republic of</option>
          <option value="Thailand">Thailand</option>
          <option value="Timor-leste">Timor-leste</option>
          <option value="Togo">Togo</option>
          <option value="Tokelau">Tokelau</option>
          <option value="Tonga">Tonga</option>
          <option value="Trinidad and Tobago">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
          <option value="Tunisia">Tunisia</option>
          <option value="Turkey">Turkey</option>
          <option value="Turkmenistan">Turkmenistan</option>
          <option value="Turks and Caicos Islands">Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
          <option value="Tuvalu">Tuvalu</option>
          <option value="Uganda">Uganda</option>
          <option value="Ukraine">Ukraine</option>
          <option value="United Arab Emirates">United Arab Emirates</option>
          <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
          <option value="United States">United States</option>
          <option value="United States Minor Outlying Islands">United States Minor Outlying Islands</option>
          <option value="Uruguay">Uruguay</option>
          <option value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option>
          <option value="Vanuatu">Vanuatu</option>
          <option value="Venezuela">Venezuela</option>
          <option value="Viet Nam">Viet Nam</option>
          <option value="Virgin Islands, British">Virgin Islands, British</option>
          <option value="Virgin Islands, U.S.">Virgin Islands, U.S.</option>
          <option value="Wallis and Futuna">Wallis and Futuna</option>
          <option value="Western Sahara">Western Sahara</option>
          <option value="Yemen">Yemen</option>
          <option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
          <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
        </select>
        <br>

        <label id="email_label"><b>Email</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email Address" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" autocomplete="off"
        value="<?php
          if(isset($_POST["email"])) {
            echo($_POST["email"]);
          } ?>">

        <label id="password_label"><b>Password</b></label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" id="passwd" name="passwd">

        <label id="c_password_label"><b>Confirm Password</b></label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" id="c_passwd" name="c_passwd">

          <input type="submit" class="btn form-control color-white mwc-orange-background-color" id="register" name="register" value="REGISTER" onclick="formcheck()">
          <br><br>

          <p class="text-align-center">Already have an account? <a href="index.php">Login Here</a><p>
        <br>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: I think I know what'a going on but I need the HTML to be sure.

Comment: updated with my entire <form> HTML

Comment: So far here's what I see, click the register button, it triggers a submit event and 3 functions go off, the only one I'm sure that's real is the onclick event handler: `document.getElementById("register").onclick = function () {...` The second function is an onclick attribute handler **on the button**: `... id="register" name="register" value="REGISTER" onclick="formcheck()">` The third function is on the form: `<form class="form-horizontal" action="register.php" method="post" onsubmit="return checkform()">` This is a disaster...

Comment: do you have advice to simplify the event handler?

Comment: Yes, use only one of them when submitting, if your objective is to validate use `e.preventDefault()` then do your validation then `formObj.submit()`. So remove #2 and #3 and refactor #1.

Answer (score 0):

```
let c = contact.val() + ''; // make sure it's a string
c = c.trim()                // trim it
console.log(':' + c + ':', c.length); // what is it
if (c.length !== 11) {
    document.getElementById("number_label").innerHTML = "<span style='color: red;'>Invalid contact number (must contain 11 digits)</span>";
}
```

Comment: the issue remains the same

Comment: so maybe try something like console.log(':' + c + ':'); // see what it actually is ..